# How to install Magento on MAMP Pro

Tags: macos, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I'm trying to install Magento on MAMP pro. It gives me below error.

[image]

I tried changing the Host to `localhost:8888` and `localhost:8889` but it does not work. Given that I have created a database called magento in my database.

How can I fix this.

Comment: I would personally edit my hosts file to include `127.0.0.1 example.com` and  `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` to start with. This way magento doesn't freak out and you can use web server rewrites. Secondly, ensure your MAMP install will support magento to begin with! [http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/how_to_check_if_your_host_supports_magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/how_to_check_if_your_host_supports_magento). Lastly, it should just be localhost. Check your MySQL user name and Password!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set up a new enviroment in MAMP PRO
2. Use the web browser to access to it. Verify it’s working.`(http://localhost:8888)`
3. Access to your PhpMyAdmin
4. Create a database and optionally import Sample Data.
5. Browse again your site and the Install Wizard will show. `(http://localhost:8888/mymegento)`

Tricky part is provide database name correctly. Both username and the password should be `root`.